# I need some help using COM API that takes VARIANT as a parameter

Tags: python, c++, com, variant

I'm trying to use, in Python, a COM API function that takes C++ variant as a parameter. (I'm using QAxContainer to use COM API in Python)

```
LONG ReceiveRealDataArr(BSTR sReal, VARIANT* pArrData)
// The fuction gives its results to an 1 dimensional array - pArrData
```

I can use it like the below, in C#

```
object arrData = null;
axFNDirect1.ReceiveRealDataArr("DEAL", ref arrData);
object[] obData = (object[])arrData;
```

I'd like to know what kind of type I should set as the parameter in Python, to use the function. I'd appreciate it if I could get any advices or keywords related to the problem.

Comment: `VARIANT` is a C structure defined here:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms221627(v=vs.85).aspx  And can be found in `OaIdl.h`

Comment: @Richard Critten Thank you for your answer. Do you happend to know how to use it in Python?

Comment: http://docs.activestate.com/activepython/3.4/pywin32/html/com/win32com/HTML/variant.html